# Time field query

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to achieve the following query using Django:

```
select * from Days where '11:00' between start_time and '23:59';
```

My (simplified) model looks like this:

```
class Days(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()
```

I want to find any object that is between start_time and midnight given a time parameter. I would like to do something like this but it isn't working.

```
time_param = datetime.time(11, 0, 0)

days = Days.objects.filter(time_param__range=[start_time, time(23, 59, 59))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
time_param = datetime.time(11, 0, 0)

# days = Days.objects.filter(time_param__range=[start_time, time(23, 59, 59))
days = Days.objects.filter(start_time__range=[time_param, time(23, 59, 59))
```

Your `time_param` variable is the one that goes inside `range` and `start_time` is the field for your `Days` model so it goes inside your `filter` query

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I am looking for. Your suggestion will try to see if start_time is within the range between time_param and 23:59:59, but I want to see if the time_param is within the range beteen start_time and 23:59:59. Maybe I will have to use raw SQL for this.

Comment: @Mikael did you figure it out?